# ASP.NET Web-forms custom validator not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, validation, webforms

I have a custom validator on my page for a file upload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuVendorBrief" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvVendorBriefFile" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditorValidate" ControlToValidate="fuVendorBrief" OnServerValidate="cvVendorBriefFile_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="You must upload a vendor brief PDF file.">     
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

I then also have a button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" ValidationGroup="EditorValidate" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Add Vendor Brief" />
```

I have defined my custom validator event like so...

```
protected void cvVendorBriefFile_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    CustomValidator fileUploadValidator = (CustomValidator)source;
    FileUpload vendorBriefFileUpload = (FileUpload)fileUploadValidator.Parent.FindControl(fileUploadValidator.ControlToValidate);
    args.IsValid = vendorBriefFileUpload.HasFile && vendorBriefFileUpload.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf");
}
```

This custom validator isn't even getting fired. Everything looks alright to me. If I drop a breakpoint anywhere in the server validation event it does not get hit when I click submit. I can hit breakpoints in the submit button's click event however.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** - I have other validation controls, like required field validators, on the page and they fire just fine.

**EDIT 2** - If you want the full source of the page and its codebehind then follow these links:

- [ASPX](http://pastebin.com/wzqs566f)
- [CS](http://pastebin.com/ADpQ8Sc0)

Comment: if you add a breakpoint it doesn't break into?

Comment: No, as stated in the question, breakpoints in the server validation event `cvVendorBriefFile_ServerValidate` do *not* get hit. Breakpoints in the button click event *do* get hit.

Comment: The two answers provided right now are wrong, I made a lab with your code and it work, you have something else, maybe in the client side. the code break into the validation when I press the button. Try it, copy paste your code in a fresh page. (update: the answers are not wrong, they just don't solve your question)

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to have to play with this further. I just did the same thing and you are correct. Everything works fine in a fresh page. I'm stumped.

Comment: I added some links to full source at the end of the question.

Comment: Anything of note in the MasterPage?  Is it wrapping the ContentPlaceHolder in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: Nope, no update panels. Master page is mostly plain CSS formatting for the site template.

Comment: Try removing `ControlToValidate` entirely. Though I've never tried to validate a file upload before, most validators won't fire (except RequiredField) if the contents are empty. Taking off the control to validate should make it fire always for that group.

Comment: @jamietre Please post that as an answer because that caused it to fire. That is very weird, but as long as it fires.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try removing `ControlToValidate` entirely. Though I've never tried to validate a file upload before, most validators won't fire (except `RequiredField`) if the contents are empty. Taking off the control to validate should make it fire always for that group.

**EDIT** (Chevex) - The `ControlToValidate` was the issue, but not because it was broken. By default it will not fire on controls with no value, as stated above. Setting the custom validator control property `ValidateEmptyText="true"` solves the issue. Sad that I had to start this giant question just to find that, but now we know! :)

Comment: Thanks Jamietre. Not sure why that worked but it did. That was definitely the issue.

Comment: I think it was a poor design decision, it has caused me no end of similar headaches in the past. The practical implication is that when you have any validation for a control that isn't allowed to be empty, you must do this (and always validate) or add a `RequiredFieldValidator` first, which is just make work.

Comment: I agree. Validation controls should at least have some kind of property like `ValidateIfEmpty` or something because that's silly.

Comment: FACEPALM! There **IS** a property to validate empty values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx (I tested it an it worked). D'oh!

Comment: I was vaguely aware of that. For some reason I thought it was newish but the docs say it was added in 2.0, so yeah that would also do it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the same ValidationGroup="" to your button, and to your validators

Comment: If you look at the validator and button control, you will see that they have the same validation group.

Comment: Ah, my turn not to look carefully. Other than the causesvalidation="true", I can't think of much else. Are your  controls dynamically added to your page, versus statically declared in your .ascx / .aspx source?

Comment: They are statically declared. Maybe I will paste the full source into a paste bin and anyone interested can look at it and maybe identify any weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

For me this occurred when the validator and its related input were inside a control that had `visible="false"` set in the control mark up.  This was causing the CustomValidator to inherit the `Visible = false` property and preventing validation from firing.  On a normal page load I wasn't making the controls visible until later in the page lifecycle.

In any case if you set a breakpoint on the `Page.Validate()` method you can inspect the `Page.Validators` collection and see if a similar thing might be happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `CausesValidation="True"` to your Button declaration.

Comment: Tried it. No effect. By default it should be true anyway.

Comment: Me too. It works on a fresh page. But something must be weird here. I posted the full source.

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22ASP%3aCUSTOMVALIDATOR%22);k(VS.HTMLDESIGNER.HTML);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-ASPX)&rd=true

you see

> When using validator controls, you
>   should always check the results of
>   server-side validation before
>   performing any processing. After a
>   postback but before your event methods
>   are called, the page calls the
>   validator controls and aggregates
>   their results into the Page.IsValid
>   property. (You can also call the
>   validator controls explicitly using
>   the Validate method.) In your own
>   code, you should check that the
>   Page.IsValid property returns true
>   before processing input. Even though
>   script-enabled browsers might prevent
>   a postback from occurring on the
>   client if a validation check has
>   failed, you should always also check
>   Page.IsValid in server code before
>   processing validated data.

So, are in testing for `Page.IsValid` in your Page Load?

Comment: I pasted the button click event a minute ago, and I had the entire thing wrapped in an `if (Page.IsValid)` block. I removed that code and instead pasted links to the full code pages. If you follow the [CS](http://pastebin.com/ADpQ8Sc0) link you will see the button click event is wrapped in the IF statement.

Comment: In the disconnected world of the web, your edit appeared (to me) at the same time I posted. Sorry my post was not more helpful to you.

Comment: No worries. Just letting you know.

Comment: Ok, try something please. Instead of testing for "IsValid" inside your click event, try it in Page_Load in an `else` under the `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: Okay, will do. Give me a min.

Comment: Ok, the way I was reading the doc "_you should always check the results of server-side validation before performing any processing_" made me think there was something to this line. I also noticed that **their** examples were just like yours... color me confused.

Comment: I know right!? Now for some reason *removing* the ControlToValidate property made it start working... That's weird.

Comment: When I've created CustomValidators I've largely ignored the ControlToValidate property. After all, a CustomValidator can really validate against any number of properties, or not properties at all. But still, interesting that it did this.